# Get all woocommerce product names with price and show using core php

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to get all woocommerce product name with their prices and want to show to a custom core php file which is not a wordpress.

**Note:** I have successfully connected to the woocommerce project's database i need custom sql query to show all woocommerce products on my core php homepage.

Comment: It'd be easier and safer to use the REST API

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce stores the product data as custom post type. You find the data in the [wp_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) and [wp_postmeta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) table.